# Umbraco 7 membership views not working in Internet Explorer 9 and below

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco project which is using the built-in membership functionality (including the default login/register views) and in modern browsers everything works perfectly.

Unfortunately, I want to support Internet Explorer 8 + 9 and I'm unable to login using these browsers; after the form data is posted, the form is reloaded with validation errors, stating 'The Username/Password field is required'.

I think this is an angular issue as opposed to a purely Umbraco one - but does anyone know of a fix for this issue?

Comment: Couldn't it be a jQuery.validation.js issue? I seem to remember the built-in views use it. jQuery 2+ has no support for IE8, so maybe try finding some older version or another validation framework? :-/

Comment: hey jannik - thanks for the reply. I did try an older validation.js library but it still didn't work. I even took validation off altogether and it still didn't work! Argh!

Comment: It's not something like your IE being set to block cookies or anything like that?

Comment: Can you login to the backend of the CMS? Also are there any console errors?